# Issue comparing textfield with an output in the avgAmount label (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am new to Swift, please ignore my dumb mistakes.

I am trying to create an app where housemates can add their grocery amounts and in result the app gives total grocery, avg, and the amount housemates owe to each other.
I am stuck at owing amounts part where I have to compare the textfield amount with the avg amount so if it is greater I can print "this much amount to owe" in the label after calculation.

This me an error "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Bool'" in the last if let "owingAm" line

Here's my full code for that button:

```
 @IBAction func calcButton(_ sender: Any)
    {
        
        let amount1 = Double(txtField1.text!)
        let amount2 = Double(txtField2.text!)
        let amount3 = Double(txtField3.text!)
        let amount4 = Double(txtField4.text!)
        
        
        if txtField1.text == "" || txtField2.text == "" || txtField3.text == "" || txtField4.text == ""
            {

                // Alert
                let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please fill in all fields", preferredStyle: .alert)

                // Add actions to the menu
                let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler:nil);optionMenu.addAction(cancelAction)

                // Display the menu
                self.present(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        else
            {
                //adding grocery amount
                let totalGrocery = amount1! + amount2! + amount3! + amount4!
                groceryTotal.text = "Total grocery: $\(totalGrocery)"

                //taking out average grocery
                let amountAvg = totalGrocery / 4
                avgAmount.text = "Per person: $\(amountAvg)"
                
                //calculating owing amounts
                //var avgAm:Int = avgAmount
                
                if let owingAm = Double(txtField1.text!)! > amountAvg
                {
                    owingAmounts.text = "Syed owes you \(owingAm)"
                }
                

 }
```

Comment: Your condition should be like this  ```if let owingAm = Double(txtField1.text!), owingAm > amountAvg```

Answer (score 0):

If change your last if statement with this code it should work. But all your code is better to be refactored to follow better coding stadats.

```
guard let amount1 = Double(txtField1.text),
      amount1 > amounting else { return }
owingAmounts.text = "Syed owes you \(amount1)"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This should help me and also, how do I improve my coding standard?

Comment: This looks better I think [link](https://pastebin.com/dHCNJADK)